# How to search for something in Database using search box in vb.net/asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

I am having a library system database. I want to include a search box where I can search for a book name. I am using sql server. I know how to write a sql statement using the LIKE %''% clause, but the thing is I am writing this sql statement in a separate file and include that in the sub method in vb.net. How can I make that statement use the text entered in textbox?

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
   Dim str As String = ("Data Source=.\INSTANCE;initial catalog=example;user=sa;password=gariahat")

   Dim con As New SqlConnection(str)

   Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("select * from item where book_id like '%" + Trim(TextBox1.Text) + "%'", con)

   Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)

   Dim ds As New DataSet()

   If (da.Fill(ds, "item")) Then

       ItemDataGridView.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)


       MessageBox.Show("match found")

   Else

       MessageBox.Show("match not found")

   End If

End Sub
```

I know this sub will work if I include the sql statement in the sub itself. But I use squaler to store my sql stored procedures and use those file in my sub, that file does not accept 'textbox.text'.

Example:

```
Public Shared Sub AccountDeposit(ByVal value As Integer, ByVal AccountNumber As String, ByVal connection As SqlConnection)
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("AccountDeposit", connection)
    cmd.CommandType = Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AccountNumber", AccountNumber)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Value", value)
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
End Sub
```

Here "AccountDeposit" is my stored procedure which i included in my sub.I want to do similar thing here but dont know how to include the text in textbox to sql statement

Comment: It's not quite clear what *"... include that in the sub method ..."* means. You should include an example of a those files to make clear what you mean. If you are creating stored procedures, your command needs to provide the text input as a parameter - which your sql statement should do as well because currently your code is vulnerable to [SQL Injection](https://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: NEVER EVER EVER build up a string like that and execute it. Read about, understand and start using parameters before bobby tables (see link above) comes to visit. You also should be wrapping your connection and commands in a USING statement. As coded your connection pool is going to get decimated with connections left open and stranded.

Comment: @Learner , please don't add that much code in a comment. It is too hard to read. Delete your comment and add the code to your question with the edit option.

Comment: @SeanLange I will look into it. Thanks.